# list.remove() error in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, android-recyclerview

i have list and each row has checkbox , I'm try to get all checkboxes postions then loop over it and remove each row with list.remove(indexOfpostion)
but it throws  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Note: my list name is " Dish " .

code :

```
 public void removeAtAll() {


    Iterator it = selectedCheckBox.entrySet().iterator();
    if(!it.hasNext()){

        new makeDialog().makeDialog(mContext,mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.share_no_data));

    }
    else {
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            int key = (Integer) pair.getKey();
            if ((Boolean) pair.getValue()) {
                //  it.remove();
                DishToDel.add(dish.get(key).getDishID());

            }
        }
            //
        for (Object o : selectedCheckBox.entrySet()) {
            Map.Entry pair2 = (Map.Entry) o;
            int key2 = (Integer) pair2.getKey();
            if ((Boolean) pair2.getValue()) {

                dish.remove(getItem(key2));  // error here 
                notifyItemRemoved(key2);
                notifyItemRangeChanged(key2, dish.size());
            }
        }
        chooseAllradioButton.setSelected(false);
        favhtask = new FavAsyncTaskDelete(mContext, DishToDel);
        favhtask.execute();
    }
    // process message deleteing

}
```

Error log

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.TopLine.nokhbatalatbaq, PID: 32327
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
    at com.TopLine.nokhbatalatbaq.adapter.FavAdapterDishes.removeAtAll(FavAdapterDishes.java:344)
    at com.TopLine.nokhbatalatbaq.adapter.FavAdapterDishes$4.onClick(FavAdapterDishes.java:151)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6205)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23653)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Comment: can you add the error log?

Comment: done , note that , that my list of dishes when it has three selected boxes then in last one try to remove from list it try to get position = 2 , but list now has only one element in position 0 , so how to remove some rows from my list just once ?

Comment: what your getItem does most likely this method is not able to adjust itself on list shrink but its only assumption.

Comment: DO. NOT. USE. RAW. TYPES!

Answer (score 0):

You removed an item from the entry set using `dish.remove(getItem(key2))` while you iterated over the entry set, which I would have expected to throw `ConcurrentModificationException`, but apparently you have some `List` that you failed to show us that perhaps is used by `getItem`, which you also failed to show us, so maybe that's why the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Also, why are you invoking a static method on `DishToDel`? That seems like the sort of call that should be to an instance method.

Normally you should be able to loop-and-remove in a single iterator-based loop, but you have complicated matters too much to know exactly what you're trying to do.

Separate creation of whatever

```
new makeDialog().makeDialog(mContext,mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.share_no_data));
```

is trying to create from the method `removeAtAll` and assign the result to something, or pass it somewhere, so that it isn't just a useless line. Methods should have a single purpose​, not multiple, and especially not contradictory purposes.

Once you've cleaned up your code you'll find it much easier to diagnose any bugs, and to seek help for them. If you do seek help, give a complete example that demonstrates your issue. Don't suppress all the relevant information.

And DO NOT USE RAW TYPES!